# .aspx links are opening in IE11, not Microsoft Edge, even when Edge is my default browser

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have an application which contains some links in the footer. These links are of type `.html` and `.aspx`. Now if I set Microsoft Edge as the  default browser (using default programs), then, when trying to open this links from my application, the `.html` links are opening in Edge, while `.aspx` links are opening in IE 11, even though Edge is my default browser. I am using the Microsoft Edge Preview version.

I even tried to update the .aspx association using `Default Programs -> Set Association`, but for .aspx page it is not showing Microsoft Edge in the list as a choice.

While the same case is working fine on IE11 on Windows 10 Preview version.

Comment: When you say 'an application', do you mean a standalone Win32 application or a Windows Store app, rather than the links being on a web page opened locally (file: URL) or on a regular website? If it's an app, rather than a page loaded in Edge, what's it written in? What control implements those links?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have compatibility mode turned off and that you don't have any compatibility tags or user agent strings in the aspx pages your are linking to. Also, make sure you are using the correct  and have the correct meta tag, .

We've been testing our applications on Edge for a while now and these are the two biggest issues encountered.

Comment: Hi SwadeWorx,Thanks for the suggestion. But I am not using any meta tag on my aspx page to which I am linking. Even my compatibility mode is turned off too.